# what is the use of Eval() in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What is the use of `Eval()` in ASP.NET?

Comment: Wait, wait.  I can only tell you the answer to one of those, so please, choose wisely.  (You may wish to edit your question).

Comment: You forgot to ask how it's used. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Eval is used to bind to an UI item that is setup to be read-only (eg: a label or a read-only text box), i.e., Eval is used for one way binding - for reading from a database into a UI field.

It is generally used for late-bound data (not known from start) and usually bound to the smallest part of the data-bound control that contains a whole record. The Eval method takes the name of a data field and returns a string containing the value of that field from the current record in the data source. You can supply an optional second parameter to specify a format for the returned string. The string format parameter uses the syntax defined for the Format method of the String class.

Comment: Eval method is to receive data and bind to UI control. But how the data has been sent? if there is a eval method "Text="<%#Eval("data1")%>"", how the data1 to be sent?

Answer (score 37):

While binding a databound control, you can evaluate a field of the row in your data source with eval() function.

For example you can add a column to your gridview like that :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourFieldName" />
```

And alternatively, this is the way with eval :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YourFieldName") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It seems a little bit complex, but it's flexible, because you can set any property of the control with the eval() function :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "ShowDetails.aspx?id="+Eval("Id") %>' 
          Text='<%# Eval("Text", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I wish I had a dollar for every time I forget to use single quotes on the tag attribute when I used double quotes in Eval

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ```Text='<%# Eval("Text", "{0}") %>'```
How does it work?

Comment: @Canavar Can i multiply an Eval and a variable?

Answer (score -2):

IrishChieftain didn't really address the question, so here's my take:

eval() is supposed to be used for data that is not known at run time. Whether that be user input (dangerous) or other sources.