# Show images in datalist ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to show Images in my datalist. Image URLs are stored in my database. For some reason urls can't be retrived from my database.

Anyone knows what Am I missing? Here is my code.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="http://mywebsite.com/folder/{0}" Width="100%" />

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>


     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [url] FROM [MyDatabase]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: are the images in same server ?

Comment: Yes. They are just in different folder. As final link I receive that kind of url. http://mywebsite.com/folder/%7B0%7D. I'm not that familiar with asp.net , so I would need some assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in binding image to image control. Try this.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "http://mywebsite.com/folder/" + Eval("url") %>' Width="100%" />
```

Or

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/folder/" + Eval("url") %>' Width="100%" />
```

Comment: Awesome. It works! Before I accept your answer can you answer me this. What does "Eval" mean?

Comment: check this link here is explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793274/what-is-the-use-of-eval-in-asp-net

Comment: you can also see this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623516/The-evil-of-Eval-in-ASP-NET