# How do we access loop variable and bind variable in ASP.Net Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a peculiar case in ASP.Net Web Forms. I have a repeater in which I want to loop through a list and generate controls dynamically.

If I use `<%#`,

```
<% for (var index = 1; index < MyNamespace.Model.Count; index++)
{ %>
    <div style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval(String.Format("v{0}_vendor_name", index.ToString())) %>: </div>
 <% } %>
```

I can access Eval but not my loop index variable. I get below build error:

> The name 'index' doesn't exist in the current context.

If I use `<%=`,

```
 <% for (var index = 1; index < MyNamespace.Model.Count; index++)
{ %>
    <div style="font-weight: bold"><%= Eval(String.Format("v{0}_vendor_name", index.ToString())) %>: </div>
 <% } %>
```

I don't get any build errors, but at run-time, I get below error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

I have looked into a number of questions on this forum but none of them have the requirement of getting both types of variable in a single statement.

If you wonder what I'm trying to achieve, my `DataTable` bound to this `Repeater` has some dynamic columns.  I want to add them dynamically depending on the count.  So, my Eval should pick up v1_vendor_name, v2_vendor_name, if there are 2 columns.

I have `v1_vendor_name`, `v2_vendor_name` in the `DataTable` bound to this `Repeater`; Instead of using `Eval("v1_vendor_name")` and `Eval("v2_vendor_name")`, I'm trying to use a loop so the column in `Eval` is dynamically applied. I have to do this dynamically since I have no control over the number of columns. It could go up to `v10_vendor_name`.

I have tried using a property from code behind, as suggested by @tweray,

```
 for (this.index = 1; this.index < MyNamespace.Model.Count; this.index++)
   { %>
  <div style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval(String.Format("v{0}_vendor_name", this.index.ToString())) %>: </div>
 <% } %>
```

But, `this.index` in eval always takes 0 even though I assigned 1 in the loop.

Comment: Why not use a nested repeater? Or if you're able to, switch to ASP.NET MVC with the Razor view engine where this is all much cleaner and prettier looking.

Comment: @mason - Yes, It works in MVC.  But, I have to plug-in a change to an existing Web Form application.  How do you think a nested repeater works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apparently is not similar to MVC to loop through in Repeater with Bind variables.

When there is a bind variable in Repeater, it expects that field to be present in the data set bound to that control irrespective of conditions present in HTML.  It doesn't pre-validate conditions.

For this scenario, I changed my data set to multiple rows instead of dynamic columns and handled with a nested repeater.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of `Eval()`, look at this answer to find [what is Eval() use for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793317/4773983).

That beign said, if your remove Eval from your code, you should be good to go:

```
<% for (var index = 1; index < 3; index++)
{ %>
    <div style="font-weight: bold"><%= String.Format("v{0}_vendor_name", index.ToString()) %>: </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: That will print a static output "v1_vendor_name", "v2_vendor_name" etc... I  want `Eval("v1_vendor_name")` and `Eval("v2_vendor_name")` at runtime.  Column names need to be passed to `Eval` dynamically to get value inside the corresponding column from my bound data

Comment: Did you try to change my `hard-coded 3` for your `MyNamespace.Model.Count`?

Comment: Problem with your code is at `<%= String.Format("v{0}_vendor_name", index.ToString()) %>`

Comment: What problem exactly? does it crash? I just remove the Eval() and replace your Model for a fixed number